# Xcode -replace a string in code

Tags: xcode

It seems simple but i couldn't find an answer for it .

I want to replace all strings in my code in a certain class only, with another strings .

so anywhere in the class where i have :

```
 [self.instance setObject:@"403911" forKey:@"something-design"];
 [self.instance setObject:@"403911" forKey:@"somethingelse-art"];
```

so it will become :

```
[self.instance setObject:@"403911" forKey:@"something-DESIGN"]; //replace only the word design
 [self.instance setObject:@"403911" forKey:@"somethingelse-ART"];
```

or some other word i will choose.

Comment: replace all `-design"];` with `-DESIGN"];`?

Comment: I have more than 100 of them and other different names i want to change..

Comment: You mean `-xxx"];` to `-XXX"];` and there are more than 100 `xxx`s?

Comment: yes thats it.. just a way to replace words in your code, seems strange that there isn't ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Xcode can't do that, but you can copy the whole code into `Sublime Text`, then use regular expression `-(\w+)"];` to match all the suffixes, finally you could `Upper Case` all suffixes.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 12.4, the "Replace" and "Replace all" buttons magically appear when pressing "cmd-option-shift F". Probably also in earlier versions.